# How to detect the exception instance type in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

How to get confirm the exceptions types in jsp. I have printed `Exception` using **ex.printStackTrace(response.getWriter())** method, but it is not professional way to show the exception to the user.

Suppose i am getting **Connection** expression. it arrives the exception but it will directly writes the exception on the document of HTML. it will doesn't ***gives/return*** value. I want show the professional error to the user like `DB Connection Error` only not lot of line code.

Comment: Do you know that don't have to use `ex.printStackTrace`? You can place any code you want in the `catch` block and so you can generate any kind of output.

Comment: you are saying that use custom message print in the catch block. I know that but by default we got only exception object in JSP. There is no any way to detect the specific exception so. I have solved it my own Idea, That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I got solution on this issue. I have solved it as following code snippet.

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <% 
        try{
            throw exception; // it will gives exception as new, and you can get Exception type
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            out.println("<h3 style='color:red'>DataBase Connection Error</h3>");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(resopnse.getWriter());
        }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```